# Remotedesktop to windows 2008 server with 2 nics

Tags: windows-server-2008, routing, remote-desktop, nic

Hi I have 2 NICs on a Windows 2008 R2 Server. nic1 with ip address 192.168.2.1 with gatewaty 192.168.2.254 and nic2 with ip address 10.96.6.253 with no gateway. The windows 2008 server is connected to a router which is connnected to another router so if I want to connect to the windows 2008 server I use 192.168.0.31 because it is forwarded. If I use remote desktop to connect to that machine I use 192.168.0.31 and that works well, but the server has a seccond nic and I want to be able to connect with a remotedesktop to nic2. Any help appreciated!

[server windows 2008 r2 192.168.2.1] --> [router 192.168.2.254/192.168.0.31] --> [my computer 192.168.0.13 gateway 192.168.0.254]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly the second NIC does not have a gateway address, typically that means the server has no routable path to the internet, so without that you won't be connecting over the second NIC.

You can however multi-home a NIC.  In other words a NIC can have multiple IP addresses/subnets, and gateways.  So on NIC2 you could have assigned the following IPs/Gateways:

- 10.96.6.253 -> No Gateway
- 192.168.2.1 -> 192.168.2.254

This all assumes of course that NIC 2 is connected to a switch that eventually connects to the gateway 192.168.2.254

Hope that helps.

Comment: The nic2 10.96.6.253 is directly connected to a adsl modem. It is a special line which is used for a department. but to acces it you can only get there if you are on the server 192.168.2.1 and start their a remote desktop. But I want to start direct a remotedesktop from my client to that nic2 without first remotedesktop to 192.168.2.1 I hope you understand what I mean?

Comment: You would have to have a router, either hardware or software along the wire/path. You essentially want to tunnel through the server to the remote site, and in order to do that you would have to setup a routable path through the server.  Of course you could just terminate the ADSL line to the rest of your network and then setup the proper NAT and routing rules to send traffic there. Lots of options, none real simple to implement unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: I still don't know how I can set it up. Could you be specific?

Comment: In it's simplest form, setup a proxy server on the box that is connected to your ADSL connection, then when you connect, use the proxy server.  Essentially you're network connection should pass through the other server, which will then go to the remote box. That's the simplest setup.